# Negative-log-likelihood dimensions in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, dimensions

*(Any better way to input markdown?)*

I'm starting to attempt to learn how regularized multi-class logistic regression classifiers work, but I'm stuck at one of the first steps. The negative log-likelihood function of logistic regression for $m$ classes and its gradients are given by:

[image]

If I have a feature matrix $\bf X$ that is size `800K x 50`, What are the dimensions of $\bf W$, $\bf w_{k}$, $\bf x_{j}$, and what do $n$ and $m$ equal?

---

I thought that $m=50$, $n=800K$, $\bf W$ is also a `800K x 50` matrix, $\bf w_{k}$ is a column of $\bf W$ of size `800K x 1`, and $\bf x_{j}$ is a row of $\bf X$ of size `50 x 1`. However obviously I'm wrong because I can't take the dot product $\bf w_{k}^{T} \bf x_{j}$ if these vectors have unequal lengths. What part(s) am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think this question is more related to Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `n=500k` samples, each is represented by 50 features. So, the number of features is 50. The number of classes, `m`, is not mentioned in your question (it is not 50). $\bf W$ is the weight matrix which can be seen as a `50 x m` matrix. The $\bf w_{k}$ is a column of $\bf W$ which is a vector of size 50 x 1. About `x` you are right: $\bf x_{j}$ is a row of $\bf X$ of size 50 x 1.